# Prove there is a unique function $g : B \rightarrow A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, relations

I was wondering if someone would not mind proofreading my demonstration for the following problem. Any sentences in brackets [] will be omitted in the formal proof.

**Problem**

Let $B$ be a set, let $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ be sets for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $h_i : B \rightarrow A_i$ be a function for each $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$. Prove that there is a unique function $g:B\rightarrow A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n$ such that $\pi_i \circ g = h_i$ for all $i \in \{1,\dotsc, n\}$ where $\pi_i:A_1 \times \cdots A_n \rightarrow A_i$ is the projection map.

**Proof**

**Existence**

Set $I$ to be an indexing set such that $I = \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $h_i:B \rightarrow A_i$ for each $i \in I$. Let $b \in B$. Iterating through the values of $i$, we have a sequence of images $h_1(b), \dotsc, h_n(b)$. If the set $A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$ is a Cartesian product for each $A_i$, then the $n$-list $(h_1(b), \dotsc, h_n(b)) \in A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$. Thus, we have an ordered pair $(b,(h_1(b), \dotsc, h_n(b)))$. Define the relation $g:B \rightarrow A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$. Then $(b,(h_1(b), \dotsc, h_n(b))) \in g$.

To prove that $g$ is a function, we first note that for every $b \in B$, the function $h_i$ gaurantees the (unique) existence of an image $(h_1(b),\dotsc,h_n(b)) \in A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$. To prove uniqueness, let the images $x = g(b)$ and $y = g(b)$ for each $b \in B$ such that $x \neq y$. Thus, the n-lists $x = (h_1(b),\dots, h_n(b))$ and $y = (h_1(b),\dotsc, h_n(b))$ have at least one differing component $j$ where we denote $h_j(b)$ to be the $j^{th}$-component of $x$, and $h^*_j(b)$ to be the $j^{th}$ componenet of $y$. Therefore, $h_j(b) \neq h^*_j(b)$. But this implies that $h_j$ is not a function for an arbitrary $j \in I$, which is a contradiction.

Hence, $g$ is a function.

Now construct the composition $\pi_i \circ g: B \rightarrow A_i$.
We will prove that $\pi_i \circ g = h_i$.

We first note that the domain and codomain of $\pi_i \circ g$ and $h_i$ are equal by construction.

We now prove that for all $b \in B$, we have $h_i(b) = \pi_i(g(b))$ for all $i \in I$

Choose any $m \in I$.

First, let $b \in B$. Then $h_m \in A_m$. By definition of $\pi_i \circ g$, the fact that $h_m \in A_m$ for an arbitrary $m \in I$ implies that $(b,h_m(b)) \in \pi_i \circ g$, so $h_i \subseteq \pi_i \circ g$.

Now, since we are assuming that $b \in B$, we have $g(b) \in A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$. Then applying $\pi_m$ to $g$, we deduce that $\pi(g(b)) \in A_m$. By definition of $h$, we must have $(b, \pi_m(g(b))) \in h_m$. Therefore, $\pi_i \circ g \subseteq h_i$.

We conclude that $\pi_i \circ g = h_i$ for each $i \in I$.

**Uniqueness**

Suppose to the contrary that there are two functions $g:B\rightarrow A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$ and $g':B\rightarrow A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$ such that $h_i = \pi_i \circ g$, $h_i = \pi_i \circ g'$ for all $i \in I$, and $g(b) \neq g'(b)$ for some $b\in B$ [This implies that some of the components of $g(b)$ and $g'(b)$ are not equal; recall that $g(b) \in A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$, which means that the element $g(b) = (a_1,\dotsc,a_n)$ for some $a_i \in A_i$]

Let $b \in B$. For each $m \in I$, we have $h_m(b) \in A_m$. From our premise, we know that $h_m = \pi_m(g(b))$ and $h_m = \pi_m(g'(b))$. We note that we cannot have $\pi_m(g(b)) \neq \pi_m(g(b))$, because then $h_m$ would not be a function. Hence, $\pi_m(g(b)) = \pi_m(g'(b))$.

However, observe that $\pi_m(g(b))$ is an arbitrary component of the preimage $g(b)$. Thus the equality $\pi_m(g(b)) = \pi_m(g'(b))$ implies that the components of $g(b)$ and $g'(b)$ are equal, entailing that $g(b) = g'(b)$.

Hence the function $g = g'$. Therefore, there exists a unique function $g: B \rightarrow A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$ such that $\pi_i \circ g = h_i$ for all $i \in I$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: You have at most showsn that there exixts *at most one* such function when the task is to show that there is *exactly one* such function

Comment: 1st paragraph: You don't want to assume that $g, g'$ differ for **all** $b\in B$, just for at least *one* $b\in B$. 2nd para: "because then $h$ would not be a function" — not really the way to say it. $h_m$ (not $h$, there is no $h$) *is* a function, and everything is equal to itself. // This shows uniqueness. You should also show existence! What's the definition of $g$?

Comment: @BrianO Thank you for pointing out the logical issue regarding the first paragraph, and for pointing out the typo in the second paragraph; indeed, $h$ does not exist in this context (poor $h$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof you gave is correct. However, you only prove uniqueness where you should also prove existence. In general, when you are asked to prove that "there exists a unique" something, you have to prove that there actually exists such an object, **and** that it is unique.

---

The proof of existence is not correct. You cannot start by assuming you have such a function $g$, you must instead start with the maps $h_i$ and show that you can construct such a $g$.

Comment: I made the emendation. If you would be so gracious as to rereading my proof when you get the chance, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: So I tried again. This time I used the maps $h_i$ to form a sequence of images whose Cartesian product belongs to $A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_n$. Then I have an ordered pair, so I introduced the relation $g$ to which the pair belongs. I then prove that $g$ is a function, prove that the composition is equal to $h_i$, and then demonstrate uniqueness. If I am still wrong, then I am lost on how to go about showing that $g$ exists.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire Good, now your proof is correct :) Good luck with your studies!